# trying to put an icon font Inside of my button

Tags: html, css

I´m trying to put an icon font inside my search input at the right side.

I´m putting the icon font `<i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i>` inside my `<button>` tag, but the icon font is appearing at the right of my search input and not inside the input at right.

Somebody there can see what is happening?

**My jsfiddle with the problem:**
http://jsfiddle.net/ritz/ZNb5r/ (I try to link the "font-awesome.min.css" into the jsfiddle but I think its not working)

**My html:**

```
<li style="float:right; list-style:none; height:20px;">
  <form id="search">
        <input name="q" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Search..." />
        <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></button>
   </form>
 </li>
```

**My css:**

```
    #search 
        {
              margin-top:8x;
              margin-top:8px;
              outline:none ;
              border:none ;
        }


    #search input[type="text"] 
        {
              border: 0 none;
              font:  12px 'verdana';
              background: brown;
              text-indent: 0;
              width:110px;
              padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
              -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
              -moz-border-radius: 20px;
              border-radius: 20px;
              text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); 
              -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
              -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
               box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
               -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
               -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
               -o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
               transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
         }

    #search input[type="text"]:focus 
             {
               background: #141d22;
               color: #fff;
               width: 170px;
               outline:none;
               color:000;
               -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
               -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
                box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
                text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
           }


    button[type="submit"]>i:hover
           {     
               color: #fff;

            }   

     button[type="submit"]>i
            {
                background:none;
                color:#ccc;
                font-size:1.5em; 

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

The icon **will not** appear inside your input, because your button is not and can not be nested inside an input.

To make your button appear inside the input, try this:

```
 <style type="text/css">
     * {
         -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
         -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
         box-sizing: border-box;
     }

     #search input[type="text"] {
         padding-right: 20px;
     }

     #search button[type="submit"] {
         margin-left: -20px;
         width: 20px;
     }
 </style>
```

You may have to tweak margins and paddings to get it to work properly. To eliminate some trouble, I've added box sizing. Why?

> [By default] The width and height properties are measured including only the content, but not the border, margin, or padding.

When you use border-box, however,

> The width and height properties include the padding and border, but not the margin.

(See MDN's article on box-sizing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Answer (score 1):

You just aren't linking to the font-awesome css file correctly.  Here is my **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s4wuQ/1/)** with it working properly.

To make it work all I did was link it to the CDN by adding this `http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css` to external resources.

Comment: I assumed FontAwesome just didn't work in the Fiddle. I think he wants the icon to appear *inside* the input.

Comment: You sir, are correct... I misunderstood what he was saying.  I guess its just a coincidence that font-awesome wasn't working for him. Will upvote your answer.

Comment: Thanks! But I was trying to have my icon inside the button and no at the right!

Comment: @John23 Oh, well great! Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Put some `height` and `width` in the `button` tag should sholve your issue. Then make an icon as `background-image`. You may not have to put `i` tag on it, see my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aldivoz/ZNb5r/1/) using an `input` tag and `background-image` as icon.